# Trailer to have the count no.of records

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have the output schema which should look in the following format

```
Header
Memeber 01
  Benefit 01
  Benefit 02
Memeber 02
  Benefit 01
  Benefit 02
  Benefit 03
Trailer-Count 09
```

The Trailer should have the field element called count which should hold the count of the no.of records. How should we approach this should I create a custom pipeline component or  can we do this through mapping. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your message type, If your send port is designed to receive individual member messages then assembly them together, yes, a custom pipeline component shall be used.

If your message already have the Header and Trailer defined, you can simply use a map to count the member nodes count without using a custom pipeline component